# Communication between gradle methods and tasks

Tags: methods, gradle, task

I can't seem to get my collection from the method to a state where generateWadleTasks can iterate over it. At least not in a way such that I can access it. I've tried properties, parameters and return values. What's wrong with this picture?  I seem to have some misconceptions about how information is passed around either in Groovy or in Gradle... or perhaps both. An explanation of the scopes involved might help. This is a subproject.

```
buildscript{
...
}
ext.collectionOfObjects = []

class WadleProfile {
   def File wadleFile;
   def wadlArgs;
}

ext.factoryMethod = { 
  //supposed to create and add WadleProfiles to collectionOfWadleProfiles
}
compileJava {
  doFirst { factoryMethod() }
}

task generateWadlTasks {

    println "Executing generateWadlTasks"

    project.ext.collectionOfObjects.each { wadlProfile ->

        task("wadl2java" + wadlProfile.id, type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'classes') {
            main = project.wadlBaseMain
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The factory method creates a Collection ( ArrayList ) of data only objects. Each of these represents the required information regarding a particular WADL file. For each of these objects in the list, a task is created with it's name based on the file name. ...except for some reason I can't get information transfered from the methods to the task.

Comment: I've found one logical error in that I have to build my classpath with a configuration.

Comment: You know that there's no way to invoke a task created by another task?

Comment: No, I did not. Someone else recommended it as a solution to writing redundant tasks. :-(

Comment: So you know now. You can iterate over the list and create the tasks or use [task rules](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html).

Comment: So this guy is wrong? It seemed reasonable enough at the time but I've admittedly not gotten it to work. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030954/gradle-task-syntax-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Comment: No, he's right. But what he suggested can't be wrapped in a task.